# How to convert Task<Object> to List<Object>

Tags: c#

I am working on a legacy project.

```cs
public List<object> GetExternalDataSets(int dataSourceId)
{
    var dataSource = _context.DataSources.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DataSourceId == dataSourceId);
    if (dataSource != null)
    {
        if (dataSource.DataSourceType != "PowerBI")
        {
            var dbInfo = GetDataSourceInfo(dataSource);
            IExternalDbContext externalDbContext = ExternalContextFactory.GetExternalDbContext(dbInfo, config);
            return externalDbContext.GetAllTables(dbInfo.DBName);
        }
        else {
           //Part added by me
            return  powerBIService.GetPowerBIDatasetsAsync(dataSource.WorkspaceId);     
        }
    }
    return new List<object>();
}
```

I have added few new lines to it. But `powerBIService.GetPowerBIDatasetsAsync(dataSource.WorkspaceId);` is returning the type of `Task<object>`. How can I convert it to `List<object>`.

Comment: `return powerBIService.GetPowerBIDatasetsAsync(dataSource.WorkspaceId).Result;`

Comment: @fubo: Calling `.Result` directly is almost always a bad idea.  Why not `await` it properly?

Comment: OP doesn't want to change the return type / method / calling method and so on. imo `.Result` is at least a mentionable alternative

Comment: @fubo: If the method is awaiting an asynchronous operation then the method should itself be asynchronous.  *Hiding* asynchronous operations from consuming code is a recipe for bugs.  The question doesn't explicitly state that this method signature *can't* be changed, and even if it did it would need a more compelling reason than that assertion alone.  We should default to [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and only deviate when there's a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @David sure, `await` is best practice which should be the first choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By awaiting the task.  Make your method `async`:

```
public async Task<List<object>> GetExternalDataSets(int dataSourceId)
```

And await the task:

```
return await powerBIService.GetPowerBIDatasetsAsync(dataSource.WorkspaceId);
```

---

Regarding your edit...

> is returning the type of `Task<object>`. How can I convert it to `List<object>`

In that case you'd also have to add the awaited `object` to a `List`:

```
var obj = await powerBIService.GetPowerBIDatasetsAsync(dataSource.WorkspaceId);
return new List<object> { obj };
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, its work perfectly in api level. but now the response is slightly different. its returning a [[1,2,3,.....N]] in else part where it is retuning [1,2,3,.....N] in if.

Comment: @Gevin: That looks like an array of arrays.  In the question you specifically state (twice) that the asynchronous operation is returning the type `Task<object>`, but this result implies that it may be returning a `Task<List<object>>`.  Which is it and how have you confirmed that?  It's important for you to know the types you're using.  (*Especially* when you rely on `object` which pretty much eliminates most/all type checking.  You really shouldn't be relying on `object` unless you have a compelling reason to do so.)