# Method returns Task<List<Guid> instead of List<Guid> in WebAPI

Tags: c#, task, webapi

Below async method returns `Task<List<Guid>>` instead of `List<Guid>`.
Can anyone suggest how to return List?

```
public static async Task<List<Guid>> ConvertTaxRequest(Proto.GetTaxListRequest request)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return new List<Guid>(request.TaxKeyList.ToList().ConvertAll(Guid.Parse));
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure is returning a Task<List>? Because it should return a List<Guid> if you're awaiting the call.

Comment: I want to convert List<string> into List<Guid>. In my API action method excepts List<Guid>. So am doing conversion.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I got Task<List<Guid>>. @Florian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Task<Object> to List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73488821/how-to-convert-taskobject-to-listobject)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me check

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "the mistake". An async method *can't* return `List<Guid>`. How do you expect it to be asynchronous, but return a result synchronously? Please clarify the question.

Comment: "Can anyone suggest how to return List?" - You can't do so if you expect it to be asynchronous. I suggest you read up on how asynchrony in .NET works, and the purpose of the `Task` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return `List<Guid>` without any tasks, just do it:

```
public static List<Guid> ConvertTaxRequest(Proto.GetTaxListRequest request) =>
  request.TaxKeyList.Select(item => Guid.Parse(item)).ToList();
```

and you can put

```
List<Giud> myList = ConvertTaxRequest(myRequest);
```

If you *have to* return `Task` (say for API requirement) and `request...ToList()` is *fast enough*
you can construct task from the result:

```
public static Task<List<Guid>> ConvertTaxRequest(Proto.GetTaxListRequest request) =>
  Task.FromResult(request.TaxKeyList.Select(item => Guid.Parse(item)).ToList());
```

If `request...ToList()` is *slow*, then you can run it asynchronosly

```
public static Task<List<Guid>> ConvertTaxRequest(Proto.GetTaxListRequest request) => 
  Task.Run(() => request.TaxKeyList.Select(item => Guid.Parse(item)).ToList());
```

In both cases with `Task` you should *await* them

```
// Since ConvertTaxRequest returns not List<Guid>, but Task<List<Guid>>
// We should await when Task is completed
List<Giud> myList = await ConvertTaxRequest(myRequest);
```

Comment: I forgot to add Await Keyword. Thank you @Dmitry ByChenko

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet, but perhaps you didn't call your method like that:

```
await ConvertTaxRequest(obj);
```

so you got Task<List> insted of List

Comment: "Can't comment yet" - please don't use the answer functionality where you'd normally add a comment to ask for clarifications. At the moment, the question is basically unclear... I don't think it's worth speculating like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet he mean he doesn't have privilege to comment yet because his reputation is only 21 right now. I believe minimum reputation to add comment is 50

Comment: @FitriHalim: Yes, I know. I'm saying that "I can't leave a comment as a comment, so I'll effectively leave a comment as an answer" isn't appropriate.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thank you, i will not repeat same mistake.